# placeholder style text in resx file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, localization

Is there any way to add text in a resx file  like

```
'{0}'
```

within a localized string where the intention is NOT that {0} should act as a placeholder, but rather as regular text within a localized string

(I'm using asp.net-mvc)

**Edit**

Sorry, my question is incorrect - I'm actually getting {0} Even without using String.Format

Answer (score 2):

You should use the same technique as in all MVC to output any string as is:

```
var a = @Html.Raw(Resources.Admin.Name);
```

this will output as

```
var a = '{0}';
```

using

[image]

---

**`Html.Raw`** will output the exact string as your wrote, without encoding it.

Comment: not sure what I'm doing wrong, but as long as i use the {0} in the resx file without String.Format i get this error:Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Comment: Here's a snippet: <h2>@RegisterResources.CreateANewAccount</h2>
<p>
      @Html.Raw(RegisterResources.Instructions);
</p> - where RegisterResourecs is the name of the resources file, Instructions is the key, and the value of the key contains {0}

Comment: Sorry, I think my question is incorrect - I'm actually getting {0} even without @Html.Raw. Thanks. +1 for help... but I think I should delete the question